# Grant issue while creating Dependent View in

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

When I try to create a view by using different tables(from different users), getting `grant option does not exist for (dependent table)` even though Privileges(`WITH GRANT OPTION`) exists on dependent tables to respective user but when I execute same dependent `Select` query of creating view it's running successfully.

```sql
create or replace view ein.eswar
as
select * from ron.anil t ,msd.ram v where t.id=v.id;
```

> ```
> grant option does not exist for ron.anil;
> ```

After dropping view and recreating it successfully without any issues. Please explain.

Comment: Just to clarify, you've dropped the view and re-created it and the second time it has worked? And your question is "Why did it not work the first time?" or is it "Why did it work the second time?" .... either way, I think you will get a better response if you provide a [MRE] that we can execute that replicates the problem rather than trying to guess.

Comment: I've both questions.Why did it not work the first time? and Why did it work the second time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have privilege SELECT WITH GRANT option;

```
GRANT SELECT ON ron.anil  TO EIN WITH GRANT OPTION.
```

When you are creating view on different schema then table_owner, privilege with grant option are necessary.